# Django. Не применяются стили css

Tags: css, python, django

Здравствуйте.

Есть некий css файл со стилями, который подключен к index.html таким образом:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet/css" type="text/css" href="{% static 'documents/main.css' %}" />
```

Но при запуске локального сервера стили не применяются. При этом никаких ошибок в консоли не наблюдается, и при открытии исходного кода страницы через браузер и нажатии на сам css файл я вижу его содержимое, т.е. он подключен, но почему-то не работает. И что интересно, если я подключаю less файл с точно таким же содержимым, то все отлично работает. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Правильно `rel="stylesheet"`

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, всё заработало!